# Recreate HTML from .master page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, master-pages

we are working on multiple master pages of a SharePoint 2013 environment. As a result of an misunderstanding some edits were made within the .master page instead of the html page.
I was no wondering if there is a possibility to generate the .html page out of the .master page.

Does anybody have an idea on that? 
Thank you for you help.

Regards
Constantin

Comment: When you say HTML page, are you talking about a Sharepoint wiki page, a Sharepoint publishing page, a Sahrepoint Page Layout? Can you provide a more detailed example, please?

Comment: Sorry - If I'm right SharePoint creates the .master page by processing a normal html page. Now I want to do this backwards cause our html page is out of sync with the .master which is currently used.